# How to show up/down voting item like Reddit?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to get a similar look like Reddit or HackerNews voting where up/down arrows are get stacked. What I tried rather gives me following look:

[image]

My Code is given below:

**HTML**

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
      <li class="entry">
          <div class="row">
               <div class="col-sm-2 entry__rank">
                     <span class="pull-left">1.</span>
                      <i class="fa fa-icon fa-caret-up fa-2x pull-left"></i>
                      <i class="fa fa-icon fa-caret-down fa-2x pull-left"></i>
                 </div>
                  <div class="col-md-9">
                      <span class="entry__title">
                         <a href="#">This is a great billboard</a>
                       </span>
                  </div>
             </div>
         </li>
    </ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.entry {
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.entry__rank {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: grey;
  padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
  margin-top: -10px !important;
}
.entry__title {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial;
  font-size: 16px;

}

.entry__title a {
  color: #285ddf !important;
}
```

**Desired Look**

[image]

**Event something like Stackover flow voting would work.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edited to provide a better plugin:

Using the following will probably be a better and less bloated solution:

https://github.com/janosgyerik/upvotejs

Reddit actually has their code available for people to take and basically create their own Reddit clone if they wanted:

https://github.com/reddit/reddit

Look through this and you'll probably find exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: This does not answer my question hence not helpful. I do know about Reddit source.

Comment: This plugin is awesome. Update your answer with this details and I'd accept it.

Comment: Updated, sorry for the less informative and more broad initial answer. Hope the jquery-upvote works out perfectly for you.

Comment: this is a fantastic plugin, thanks for the reference!

Answer (score 2):

U can use html button and any javascript variable to display the count.
In the button tag add onclick property and call a JavaScript method which increases the variable value on click of button
Similar approach for down count just decrease the value in the method

```
https://codeshare.io/Xv5xB
```

Answer (score 1):

Use bootstrap lib [http://getbootstrap.com/] which has more features & follow this code.

```html
<div className = "row">
     <div className = "u-full-width u-cf link-item">
      <div className = "u-pull-left link-vote">
       <div className = "u-pull-left vote-buttons">
       <div className = "arrow-up upvote" onClick={this._onVoteUp}></div>
       <div className = "arrow-down downvote" onClick=   {this._onVoteDown}></div>
      </div>
       <span className="points">{this.state.points}</span>
      </div>
      <div className="u-pull-right link-content" onClick={this._onLineClick}>
       {this.props.title}
      <span className="u-pull-right info">{domain}</span>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Write method for UpVote , DownVote & etc.

Comment: You have bootstrap installed?